# Can a MultiLabelBinarizer represent counts of values?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

Lets say we have lists in a dataframe column

```
df['a'][0] = ['earth','mars','earth','moon']
df['a'][1] = ['jupiter','pluto','sun']
```

is there a way to use a multilabelbinarizer to obtain

```
             earth   mars   moon sun  jupiter  pluto
df['a'][0]     2      1       1   0    0       0    
df['a'][1]     0      0       0   1    1       1
```

I want to translate this to a huge list of procedure codes

Comment: 1st do not name a list as list

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

planet = pd.DataFrame()
planet['planet_group'] = ['group_a', 'group_b']
planet['planet_list'] = [
    ['earth', 'mars', 'earth', 'moon'], ['jupiter', 'pluto', 'sun']]

g_planet = []
l_planet = []

for row in planet.itertuples():
    for i in row.planet_list:
        l_planet.append(i.rstrip())
        g_planet.append(row.planet_group)

data_tuples = list(zip(g_planet, l_planet))
new_planet = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['group_name', 'value'])

new_planet['value'] = new_planet['value'].apply(lambda x: [x])
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
finaldf = new_planet.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(new_planet.pop('value')),
                                       columns=mlb.classes_,
                                       index=new_planet.index))
sumdf = finaldf.groupby('group_name').agg(lambda x: sum(x))

print(sumdf)
```

the output will be like this

```
            earth  jupiter  mars  moon  pluto  sun
group_name                                        
group_a         2        0     1     1      0    0
group_b         0        1     0     0      1    1
```

what I did is change your dataset, add name for each list, then convert it to new dataframe contains name and value, where the name contains one planet from related list. then after apply to MultiLableBinarier, we group by the user and sum the value inside.

Hopes it help you.